# How can I merge two argparse Namespaces in Python 2.x?

Tags: python-2.x

I want to merge 2 `argparse.Namespace` objects in Python 2.x.

In python 3.x I can do something like this:

```
from argparse import Namespace

# The 2 initial objects
options_foo = Namespace(foo="foo")
options_bar = Namespace(bar="bar")

# the merged object
options_baz = Namespace(**vars(options_foo), **vars(options_bar))
```

And get:

```
print(options_baz)
# Namespace(foo="foo", bar="bar")
```

But in python 2.x I can't. I get the following error.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: was this useful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050873/can-two-python-argparse-objects-be-combined/38053253 it's not been super useful to me.

Comment: can I be a little bit cynic and just say...can we stop using python 2 altogether please? :P (thanks for the solution in python 3 though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've majorly reconsidered this answer, because I didn't fully read and understand your problem...

It's true that this line is valid in Python3, and invalid in Python2:

```
options_baz = Namespace(**vars(options_foo), **vars(options_bar))
```

When we look at the error, we see that it's the comma (`,`) that Python2 cannot accept:

```
  File "main.py", line 8
    options_baz = Namespace(**vars(options_foo), **vars(options_bar))
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, let's just avoid passing two sets of options to the `Namespace()` initializer:

```
...

dict_baz = vars(options_foo)
dict_baz.update(vars(options_bar))

# the merged object
options_baz = Namespace(**dict_baz)

print(options_baz)
```

and we get:

```
Namespace(bar='bar', foo='foo')
```

In another answer you pointed out that the double-star (`**`) syntax is invalid, but that's definitely valid syntax.  We can see it mentioned as far back as [Python 2.2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.2/Doc/ref/ref5.tex#L540):

> If the syntax `**expression` appears in the function call,
> `expression` must evaluate to a (subclass of) dictionary, ...

It was just that comma all along.

Comment: Even for Python 3, the solution that involves the `update` method on dictionaries is better because it supports keys that appear in both namespaces. The second namespace takes precedence over the first one.  (In the same situation, `Namespace(**vars(foo), **vars(bar))` raises an exception.)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function that merges two args:

```
def merge_args_safe(args1: Namespace, args2: Namespace) -> Namespace:
    """
    Merges two namespaces but throws an error if there are keys that collide.

    ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136549/how-can-i-merge-two-argparse-namespaces-in-python-2-x
    :param args1:
    :param args2:
    :return:
    """
    # - the merged args
    # The vars() function returns the __dict__ attribute to values of the given object e.g {field:value}.
    args = Namespace(**vars(args1), **vars(args2))
    return args
```

test

```
def merge_args_test():
    args1 = Namespace(foo="foo", collided_key='from_args1')
    args2 = Namespace(bar="bar", collided_key='from_args2')

    args = merge_args(args1, args2)
    print('-- merged args')
    print(f'{args=}')
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/brando/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/__init__.py", line 1202, in <module>
    merge_args_test()
  File "/Users/brando/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/__init__.py", line 1192, in merge_args_test
    args = merge_args(args1, args2)
  File "/Users/brando/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/__init__.py", line 1116, in merge_args
    args = Namespace(**vars(args1), **vars(args2))
TypeError: argparse.Namespace() got multiple values for keyword argument 'collided_key'
python-BaseException
```

you can find it in this library: https://github.com/brando90/ultimate-utils

---

If you want to have collisions resolved do this:

```
def merge_two_dicts(starting_dict: dict, updater_dict: dict) -> dict:
    """
    Starts from base starting dict and then adds the remaining key values from updater replacing the values from
    the first starting/base dict with the second updater dict.

    For later: how does d = {**d1, **d2} replace collision?

    :param starting_dict:
    :param updater_dict:
    :return:
    """
    new_dict: dict = starting_dict.copy()   # start with keys and values of starting_dict
    new_dict.update(updater_dict)    # modifies starting_dict with keys and values of updater_dict
    return new_dict

def merge_args(args1: Namespace, args2: Namespace) -> Namespace:
    """

    ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136549/how-can-i-merge-two-argparse-namespaces-in-python-2-x
    :param args1:
    :param args2:
    :return:
    """
    # - the merged args
    # The vars() function returns the __dict__ attribute to values of the given object e.g {field:value}.
    merged_key_values_for_namespace: dict = merge_two_dicts(vars(args1), vars(args2))
    args = Namespace(**merged_key_values_for_namespace)
    return args
```

test:

```
def merge_args_test():
    args1 = Namespace(foo="foo", collided_key='from_args1')
    args2 = Namespace(bar="bar", collided_key='from_args2')

    args = merge_args(args1, args2)
    print('-- merged args')
    print(f'{args=}')
    assert args.collided_key == 'from_args2', 'Error in merge dict, expected the second argument to be the one used' \
                                                 'to resolve collision'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the question is how to merge in python 2.x, and your answer provides a solution to merge them resolving arg collisions in python 3. As the double star ** syntax does not work in Python 2, which is clearly stated in the question.

Comment: @juanesarango, the double-star syntax is valid Python2. I've completely re-answered your question, to get down to the fundamental syntax error that prompted you to post.

Comment: @ZachYoung You definitely nailed the issue. I accepted yours as the correct answer.  Thanks!