# How to open a Python method from command line (Multiple method choices)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

First after all I'm a total newbie on Python. 
I'm trying to make a Python file with two methods like this:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello.")

def bye():
    print("Bye bye.")
```

I know an option that works with just one method.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello()
```

This will let open the file from CMD, using this command:

```
>python file.py
```

Again, it will open the file but deploying hello(), I need something to let the user pick hello() or bye() method. On internet I saw that the following CMD command

```
>python file.py hello()
>python file.py bye()
```

somehow works, but I don't know how, do someone knows?

Greetings!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle the *command line arguments*, which are available in `sys.argv`.

The most straightforward way would be:

```
import sys

def hello():
    print("Hello.")

def bye():
    print("Bye bye.")

def main():
    funcname = sys.argv[1]
    if funcname == 'hello':
        hello()
    elif funcname == 'bye':
        bye()
    else:
        print("ERROR: Invalid function")   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

An improvement on this would be to create a mapping:

```
import sys

def hello():
    print("Hello.")

def bye():
    print("Bye bye.")

def main():
    funcmap = {
        'hello': hello,
        'bye':   bye,
    }
    def invalid():
        print("ERROR: Invalid function")
        sys.exit(1)

    funcname = sys.argv[1]
    f = funcmap.get(funcname, invalid)
    f()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you want to something more complex, like the way `git` handles sub-commands, e.g. `git push origin master` and `git status`, then I would recommend using `argparse` sub-parsers. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073688/how-to-use-argparse-subparsers-correctly) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Reinhart!