# Parse different inputs into different Python functions

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a file called functions.py with several functions (func1, func2, func3.. )
I would like to write a parser that allows me to run these functions on a terminal/cluster in this way:

```
python parser.py -function func1 -inputf1_1 10 inputf1_2 20
```

and I could also do

```
python parser.py -function func2 -inputf2 'abc'
```

I know how to do this with different parser files (parser_func1.py, parser_func2.py) but I would prefer to have only one parser.py file.

This is how my code looks at the moment:

```
import argparse


def func1(x,y):
    print (x*y)

def func2(text):
    print (text)

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()


FUNCTION_MAP = {'func1' : func1,
                'func2' : func2}


# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('command', choices=FUNCTION_MAP.keys(), help='choose function to run')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

# create the parser for the "a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('func1', help='func1 help')
parser_a.add_argument("-x", "--x", required=True, help="number 1")
parser_a.add_argument("-y", "--y", required=True, help="number 2")


# create the parser for the "b" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('func2', help='func2 help')
parser_b.add_argument("-text", "--text", required=True, help="text you want to print")


args = parser.parse_args()

func = FUNCTION_MAP[args.command]
#I don't know how to put the correct inputs inside the func()
func()
```

When I now run:

```
python functions.py func1 -x 10 -y 2
```

I get this error:
usage: PROG [-h] {func1,func2} {func1,func2} ...
PROG: error: invalid choice: '2' (choose from 'func1', 'func2')

I've read these but still could not figure out how to do it:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

[Call function based on argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529610/call-function-based-on-argparse)

[How to use argparse subparsers correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073688/how-to-use-argparse-subparsers-correctly#17074215)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_subparsers` automatically adds a positional argument for you, you don't need to add the `func` argument explicitly.

However, you do need to keep track of which subparser was used. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) explain that quite well.

After you know which parser was used & which arguments to pass, you can call the specific function with keyword arguments that you construct from `args`

Here's the complete code:

```
import argparse


def func1(x,y):
    print (x*y)

def func2(text):
    print (text)

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()


FUNCTION_MAP = {'func1' : func1,
                'func2' : func2}


# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
# Just add the subparser, no need to add any other argument.
# Pass the "dest" argument so that we can figure out which parser was used.
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest='subparser_name')

# create the parser for the "a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('func1', help='func1 help')
# Keep the names here in sync with the argument names for "func1"
# also make sure the expected type is the same (int in this case)
parser_a.add_argument("-x", "--x", required=True, help="number 1", type=int)
parser_a.add_argument("-y", "--y", required=True, help="number 2", type=int)


# create the parser for the "b" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('func2', help='func2 help')
parser_b.add_argument("-text", "--text", required=True, help="text you want to print")


args = parser.parse_args()

# subparser_name has either "func1" or "func2".
func = FUNCTION_MAP[args.subparser_name]
# the passed arguments can be taken into a dict like this
func_args = vars(args)
# remove "subparser_name" - it's not a valid argument
del func_args['subparser_name']
# now call the function with it's arguments
func(**func_args)
```

Now if I call the script like this:

```
PROG func1 -x 1 -y 3
```

I get the result:

```
3
```

And if I call it like:

```
PROG func2 --text=hello
```

I get:

```
hello
```

Comment: Slightly lower down in the [sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) docs there is an example using `set_defaults` to call a specific function for each sub-command, which would be a more appropriate method here.